# Not sending data to server in Angular 6 and ASP.NET Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular6, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-http

I created a server with ASP.NET Core and front with Angular 6.

I created a form in Angular 6. In the component, I created a function for sending data to the service layer and send data to the server, but it is not entering in the server. It does not show any error.

What's the problem? Is it from the backend or the frontend?

User.ts

```
changeActive(id:number) {
    this.userService.GetUserById(id).subscribe((data) => {
        if(data.isActive)
        {
            data.isActive = false;
        } else {  
            data.isActive = true;
        }

        console.log("send data in service");
        this.userService.Active(data);
    })
}
```

Angular service :

```
public Active(user:IUser):Observable<IUser> {
    console.log("we get data from component");
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post<IUser>(this.baseUrl + 'Active', user, { headers: this.headers })
               .pipe(tap((user: IUser) => this.log(`Active user w/ email=${user}`)),
                     catchError(this.handleError<IUser>('Active user'))
          );
}
```

ASP.NET Core controller:

```
[HttpPut("Active")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ActiveAccount(User model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await _applicationUserManager.FindUserById(model.Id);
            user.IsActive = model.IsActive;
            await _applicationUserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            return Ok();
        }

        return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: Try changing `HttpPut` to `HttpPost` in your API `ActiveAccount` attribute. Either that, or do a put rather than a post.

Comment: You're not subscribing to the Observable that's returned from `Active`

Comment: @R.Richards i try that but it not work

Comment: What happens after you made the change suggested by @user184994? I expect you are getting an error message now so please include it.

Comment: it no tshow me eny error or message

Comment: Well, do you see the log message: *send data in service*? Do you see a request being made in the developer tools?

Comment: are u able to do a get request to the API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the points below one by one for your issue:

1. Call `subscribe` to handle `Active`.

   ```
   this.userService.Active(data).subscribe(result => {
     console.log(result);
   });
   ```
2. Not sure what's the value for `this.baseUrl`, it should be point to the controller address. If your controller like this, you need to append `api/sampledata` to your base url, or if you base url is `http://localhost:port`, you need to change `'Active'` to `api/SampleData/Active`.

   ```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   public class SampleDataController : Controller
   ```
3. Not sure what is your header, in general, you pass the request as `application/json`, change the action like below by adding `FromBody`.

   ```
   [HttpPost("Active")]
   public async Task<ActionResult> ActiveAccount([FromBody]User model)
   {
       //your code.
   }
   ```
4. Note the `HttpPost`, if you call `this.http.post<IUser>` from angular, you need to use `HttpPost` at controller action.
5. One more point, press `F12` in web brower to debug your client code.